# Request.el "cannot create connection to api.stackexchange.com"

Tags: api, request, elisp

I'm using the [`request.el`](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/) library (available via MELPA) to try and create a basic framework from which to start work in earnest on a [Stack Exchange mode for Emacs](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el).  All I want to do is to be able to return the object as parsed by `json-read` to the calling function, but I can't even seem to make a connection.

I understand that to have my function return the object, the call must be made synchronously, so that is what `:sync t` is there for.  I've considered making it an asynchronous call, but I don't think it would be beneficial considering its use-case.

At first, after I looked at the messages, I thought 'Maybe I don't have necessary binaries.'  I did test `request.el` with some example calls that come with its documentation, and they work fine, so that's out.

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.  I don't yet have much experience, successful or otherwise, with anything dealing with a network, and don't fully understand the error message I'm getting.  As far as I can tell, port 443 of the API is giving me the silent treatment, but I'm hesitant to think that's the case `;)`.

```
;; Works like a charm
(defun alist-to-json (alist)
  "Converts the key-value pairs of `ALIST` into a JSON-friendly
string: \"key1=value1&key2=value2&\"."
  (apply 'concat
     (mapcar (lambda (kv)
               (format "%s=%s&" (car kv)
                       (if (stringp (cdr kv)) 
                           (cdr kv)
                         (number-to-string (cdr kv)))))
             alist)))


(defvar stack-api-root "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/")

(require 'json)
(require 'request)

(defun stack-api-request (call keys-alist)
  "Makes the specified `CALL` to the Stack Exchange API with the
  key-value pairs given `KEYS-ALIST`.  For example,

  (stack-api-request \"sites\" '((page . 2) (page_size . 25)))"

  (let* ((base-call (concat stack-api-root call "?"))
         (options (alist-to-json keys-alist)))
    (request base-call
     :params options
     :parser 'json-read
     :sync t)))
```

Backtrace

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not create connection to api.stackexchange.com:443")
  signal(error ("Could not create connection to api.stackexchange.com:443"))
  error("Could not create connection to %s:%d" "api.stackexchange.com" 443)
  url-http([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "api.stackexchange.com" nil "/2.1/sites?&" nil nil t nil t] #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] (nil))
  url-https([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "api.stackexchange.com" nil "/2.1/sites?&" nil nil t nil t] #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] (nil))
  url-retrieve-internal("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"] (nil) nil nil)
  url-retrieve("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" #[128 "\302\303\304p#\210\300\305\240\210\301p\240\207" [(nil) (nil) url-debug retrieval "Synchronous fetching done (%S)" t] 5 "\n\n(fn &rest IGNORED)"])
  url-retrieve-synchronously("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&")
  request--url-retrieve-sync("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" :params "page=2&page_size=25&" :parser json-read :sync t :error (closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote request-default-error-callback) (quote "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?") args)) :url "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" :response [cl-struct-request-response nil nil nil nil nil "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" nil (:params "page=2&page_size=25&" :parser json-read :sync t :error (closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote request-default-error-callback) (quote "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?") args)) :url "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" :response #0) nil nil nil url-retrieve nil])
  apply(request--url-retrieve-sync "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" (:params "page=2&page_size=25&" :parser json-read :sync t :error (closure (t) (&rest args) (apply (quote request-default-error-callback) (quote "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?") args)) :url "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" :response [cl-struct-request-response nil nil nil nil nil "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?&" nil #0 nil nil nil url-retrieve nil]))
  request("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?" :params "page=2&page_size=25&" :parser json-read :sync t)
  (let* ((base-call (concat stack-api-root call "?")) (options (alist-to-json keys-alist))) (request base-call :params options :parser (quote json-read) :sync t))
  stack-api-request("sites" ((page . 2) (page_size . 25)))
  eval((stack-api-request "sites" (quote ((page . 2) (page_size . 25)))) nil)
  eval-expression((stack-api-request "sites" (quote ((page . 2) (page_size . 25)))) nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
```

Messages:

```
Contacting host: api.stackexchange.com:443
Opening TLS connection to `api.stackexchange.com'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 api.stackexchange.com'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 api.stackexchange.com --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect api.stackexchange.com:443 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed
Opening TLS connection to `api.stackexchange.com'...failed
```

---

[I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310300) to make sure that this was not a problem with cURL.  The call I use for `curl` is

```
curl api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites --compressed
```

From the outside looking into the `request` repository, `request` is doing this as well.  I don't know what could be going wrong.

Comment: I don't have time to look at the problem closely, but did you check it with curl backend?  Maybe this is another url.el's bug.  If you have curl (command line one, not libcurl) it will be automatically used.  I recommend using it over url.el.

Comment: @tkf thanks for reading, first of all.  I had forgotten that I'm on a crippled computer (windows, no cygwin/admin; very long and sad story) and will look into the `curl` business - I imagine there is a standalone build for Windows I can use, and I'll report back with an update.

Comment: "REQUEST [error] Error (error) while connecting to ...api.../sites"  That's a lot of error, but the code is 60 (and, assuming it's a `curl` error, "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.")  Given that I'm getting a different result, I think I'm doing it right, I just can't win between a Windows port and `url.el`.

Comment: If it is CA certificate stuff, then I guess it's not url.el's bug.  I think it's better to try to connect to the API using curl command line and open another question.  I think many people know curl than Emacs Lisp so I think (hope) you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I boiled down your example to the following snippet to reproduce your problem but it actually worked.  Can you try this one?

```
(request
 "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites"
 :parser 'json-read
 :params '((page . "2") (page_size . "25"))
 :success (lambda (&rest args) (princ (plist-get args :data))))
```

It should print some data to `*Messages*` buffer and echo area.

EDIT:  It seems that the problem in your example is that you are passing string to `PARAMS` which takes only alist.  I will change code to raise error so that it is easier to debug.

Comment: From your POST example in [the documentation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/), the string should be equivalent, no?

Comment: DATA allows string, but not PARAMS.  PARAMS goes to url and DATA mimics HTML form etc.  Probably PARAMS should accepts string, though.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Two different arguments there.  Thanks for the clear-up!!